# If you flip a fair coin 6 times, what is the probability that you will get exactly 2 tails?

Tags: combinatorics

Why the answer is $\frac{6 \choose 2 }{2^6} = 15/64$ and not $2^4 / 2^6 = 4$.

So we say there are 6 outcomes. Total # of outcomes is $2^6$ since for each outcome we have two choices. Then we say 2 are tails. Then for 2 of outcomes we have only one choice and for rest 2 e.g $2*2*2*2*1*1 = 2^4$.

So where is the mistake?

Note: I understand "choose" argument and I answered this question correctly. I just then though of another "argument" which seems to be "okay", but which gives wrong result. I want to understand why it is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"for the rest $2$ **e.g.** $2*2*2*2*1*1$"...

Exactly (e.g.=exempli gratia), and there are more examples.

For instance $2*1*2*1*2*2$ is another one.

How many in total? $$\binom62$$

This should explain the factor.

Comment: I would understand this answer if you used $H$ instead of $2$, a delimiter instead of $+$, and $T$ instead of $1$. Otherwise, I don't quite understand the intention. $2\times2\times2\times2\times1\times1=16$, which by itself is already more than the total number of combinations.

Comment: @barakmanos I am trying to stay close to the OP in the hope that this improves *his* understanding. I have no worries about yours :). Let's wait on his reaction.

Comment: I do not understand why we count ways we need to pick two values out of six for numerator while we do not count how to pick 6 out of 6 (which would be 1) for denominator, and we rather multiply 2s out

Comment: @MaharajaX let's flip $3$ times. There are $2^3=8$ possibilities in total: TTT, TTH, THT,THH, HTT, HTH, HHT, and HHH. This for the denominator. Looking for those with exactly $2$ tails in it we find $\binom32$: TTH, THT and HTT. This for the numerator wich equals the number of triples with exactly two tails (hence one head). Each outcome has probability $\frac18$ to occur. In $3$ cases bingo: two tails. Probability $\frac38$.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have exactly 2 tails that means 4 of the flips have to be heads. So now all you need to worry about is how to arrange these 2 tails or 4 heads. Since order doesn't matter you get $$\frac{6 \choose 2}{2^6}$$ or $$\frac{6 \choose 4}{2^6}$$, depending on if you're thinking about it in choosing the 4 head's positions, or the 2 tail's positions.

Comment: I understand the argument for "choose" thing. I answered question correctly. I do not understand where my second argument is wrong.

Comment: Well in your case, you could have more than 2 tails.

Comment: As soon as you say exactly 2 tails, that is an equivalent statement to saying exactly 4 heads. So basically you don't have 2 choices for the remaining 4 spots.

Answer (score 1):

Those two outcomes can be for any coin flips in any order and not necessarily the last two, therefore 6C2, the number of combinations of two among the total six.

Edit: think of it this way:
The number of choices(positions where it can occur) for first tails is six, the number of choices for second tails is five, now divide 6×5 by 2 since order among the tails isn't important. Hope this answers your question

Comment: I were not saying it is the last two.. whatever place you put 1 choice does not matter...

Comment: What are the number of ways two tails can occur among 6 coin tosses.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the statement $\color\red{\text{"for rest 2" (for the rest of the outcomes we have $2$ choices)}}$.

No, for the rest of the outcomes you also have $1$ choice, since the question says **exactly** $2$ tails.

So each one of the remaining coins must be head, leaving you with $1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1=1^6$.

Of course, this is simply not the way to solve it.

You need to count the number of combinations containing **exactly** $2$ tails, which is $\binom62$.

Equivalently, you can count the number of combinations containing **exactly** $4$ heads, which is $\binom64$.

Finally, need to divide this value by the total number of combinations, which is $2^6$.

Comment: I don't get it. 1^6 would work if we say what is probability of getting all heads or all tails. Then it works perfectly coz for each position we have only one choice, e.g 1/2^6

Comment: @MaharajaX: Yes, in that case you would use $\binom66$ or $\binom60$, both of which are equal to $1$.

Comment: cool, so why 2*2*2*2*1*1 does not work where we say that 2 positions will have only 1 choice...

Comment: @MaharajaX: Please read carefully the first statement (marked red) in my answer.